Select mock file to use based on the running Karate Scenario
I'm using Karate 1.4.0
I have some Karate Scenarios to test my application and I'm using a Karate MockServer as mocked downstream service.
To simulate edge case scenarios (e.g. empty results from downstream), I want to select a specific mock file based on the running Karate Scenario. Is there a way to know which is the Scenario that triggered the downstream mock call?
// myScenarios.feature
Scenario: scenario 123
  ...


// myDownstreamMock.feature
Scenario: pathMatches('/downstream/path/api/v0')
  ...
  def responseStatus = 200
  string mockFileName = "<NAME_BASED_ON_MY_SCENARIO_123>.json"
  def response = read (mockFileName)

At the moment the only workaround I found is to pass this information into some fields I know are propagated to the downstream (e.g. custom headers) so that I can retrieve that field in mock feature and select the proper mock file.
For example:
// myScenarios.feature
Scenario: scenario 123
  ...
  And headers {'test-id': 'scenario123'}
  When method post
  ...


// myDownstreamMock.feature

Scenario: pathMatches('/downstream/path/api/v0')
  ...
  string mockFileName = requestHeaders['test-id'] + ".json"
  def response = read (mockFileName)

This cannot work with all downstream so I need to find a better way.

You can see if the API karate.scenario gets you what you need. It will return a JSON of metadata about the currently executing Scenario. I really don't remember if it works for mocks though. If it doesn't, it may need some code contributions.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I see the data within karate.scenario are null:
{
"sectionIndex": -1,
"stepResults": [
],
"line": 0,
"description": null,
"durationMillis": 0.0,
"failed": false,
"tags": [
"ignore"
],
"executorName": null,
"name": null,
"startTime": 0,
"refId": "[0:0]",
"endTime": 0,
"exampleIndex": -1
}
